# Return stored procedure result in a list of complex type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure which calls a dynamic query which returns multiple rows.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_list_connections] @skip int, @take int = 50
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
    IF 1 = 2    -- For EF to recognize columns
    BEGIN
        SELECT CAST(1 AS int) [Id], CAST('A' AS nvarchar(100)) [Name], CAST(1 AS bit) [Sim], CAST(1 AS bit) [Device]
    END
    DECLARE @q NVARCHAR(MAX) ='';
        SET @q = N'
        SELECT DISTINCT e.[Id], e.[Name],
        CASE
            WHEN s.[Sim] IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE 1 END AS [Sim],
        CASE
            WHEN d.[Device] IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE 1 END AS [Device]
        FROM [dbo].[Employee] e
            LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Sim] s ON s.[Employee] = e.[Id]
            LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Device] d ON d.[Employee] = e.[Id]
        ORDER BY e.[Name]
        OFFSET @skip ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @take ROWS ONLY;'
    SET @q = REPLACE(@q, '@skip', @skip);
    SET @q = REPLACE(@q, '@take', @take);   

    EXEC sp_executesql @q;
END
```

I imported the procedure to EF and mapped it to a complex type. When I try to run the procedure through EF with the following code

```
var result = db.usp_list_connections(0,50);
```

It returns an error message which is the following:

> "The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once."

What am I doing wrong? How could I store the result set of this stored procedure in a variable?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to materialize your query by calling `ToList()` probably will solve your issue:

```
var result = db.usp_list_connections(0,50).ToList();
```

Comment: When I try this I get the following error message:
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The 'Sim' property on 'usp_list_connections_Result' could not be set to a 'System.Int32' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Boolean'.

Comment: @tatgergo make sure your `DatabaseContext` is connecting to the correct database. And your schema and the entity match up.

Comment: I checked and they are matching. And I connected to the correct DB.